# Bad Practice to remove the PlaceHolderFragment With API 19?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I was wondering that if I was to just remove **this**:

```
/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fuel_economy_calculator, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

and also **this** from `onCreate()`:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
```

From my Application, if it would be considered bad practice.

I have made an application that I have done exactly this (removed the above code) with and it works perfectly; however, I am curious on whether or not doing so was bad Android programming practice as I am creating a tutorial on "How-To" create an Android app from start to uploading to the marketplace.

Comment: all it is, is an auto-generated class to get you going. There is zero harm in removing it but you can rename it to actually represent what the fragment is

Comment: alright, so having not shown how to implement this stuff will not make my tutorial misleading?

Comment: again all it is, is an auto-generated class

Comment: alright, I'll accept that if you wanna post as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all it is, is an auto-generated class to get you going. There is zero harm in removing it but you can rename it to actually represent what the fragment is